# ARP -Two different Subnets

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

We have a LAN with a DHCP server, Router (DHCP disabled) and a subnet of 192.168.1.0/24. We use Xarp to scan for ARP Spoofing and have found a different subnet IP showing up on the scan, arp source 192.168.2.243 with a arp dest 192.168.2.1 and a MAC that does not belong to any of our devices.
This IP does not ping or show up in a normal cmd window arp -a. The problem is most of the time the MAC associated with this subnet is fake but occasionally the 2nd subnet will spoof a good MAC and a loss of connection occurs. Any Suggestion on how to track the orgin of this 2nd subnet?

Answer (score 1):

You can't ARP a non-local address (from the client's view). If you need to ARP it you first need to make the IP address local by adding any IP address of the subnet to a NIC. Then you can try to ping it and you'll see the MAC association in your ARP cache (if it's still there).

Check the switches' MAC tables to which port is associated with the MAC address you're looking for. I usually start out the core switch and work outward.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about changing  a NIC to the second subnet (my bad). I checked the switches but the mac does not show up , fake or made up I guess.  I'll post what I find.

Comment: If you're question is answered please don't forget to mark it.